# How to save an object after submit with decent_exposure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, decent-exposure

I'm completely at a loss! I'm using decent_exposure gem for a first time and I suppose the problem is in it. 
That's the link https://github.com/hashrocket/decent_exposure
When I submit my form, it saves nothing. All my table in database are just full of empty fields. 
This is my form

```
<%= simple_form_for book do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :author %>
    <%= f.input_field :annotation %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

This is my controller:

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :is_admin?
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  expose(:book, finder_parameter: :id, params: :book_params)
  #I've tried both expose(:book) and expose(:books)

  def create
    if book.save
      redirect_to(book)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update
    if book.save
      redirect_to(book)
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def show
  end

  def is_admin?
    if current_user.admin?
      true
    else
      render :text => 'Registrate'
    end
  end

  def book_params
    params.require(:book).permit(:name, :author, :annotation)
  end

end
```

It gives a mistake

> param is missing or the value is empty: book
>
> ```
> def book_params
>     params.require(:book).permit(:name, :author, :anotation)
>   end
> ```

If I try just expose(:book) without params and book_params method, it seems to be okay but after submitting the form all the fields are nil. What am I doing wrong? Is there any mistake in params defining? I've been thinking and trying different variants for many many times and I can't imagine where is the problem. Every help would be appreciated!

Comment: I found it! There was "attribures: :book_params" instead of "params: :book_params"

Answer (score 1):

I found it! There was "attribures: :book_params" instead of "params: :book_params"

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you change line 4 in your controller from

`expose(:book, finder_parameter: :id, params: :book_params)`

to

`expose(:book, params: :book_params)` ?

Comment: It's still the same error "param is missing or the value is empty: book" (